# Can someone explain hashes in Perl?

Tags: perl, function, pointers, hash

Main Function:

```
my %hash = {'inner1'=>{'foo'=>5},
            'inner2'=>{'bar'=>6}};
$object->State(0, %AMSValues);
```

Sent to:

```
sub State
{
   my ($self, $state, %values) = @_;
   my $value = \%values;
```

From what I know one should be a hash and the other is a pointer, but...

[image: Hash Values]

It doesn't look like the picture is working so,

```
$value = $value->{"HASH(0x52e0b6c)"}
%values = $values->{"HASH(0x52e0b6c)"}
```

Comment: Did you mean to pass `%hash` to the `State` method?  I don't know where `%AMSValues` came from.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`use warnings;` always.

Your:

```
my %hash = {'inner1'=>{'foo'=>5},
            'inner2'=>{'bar'=>6}};
```

is incorrect; `{}` generates an anonymous hash reference, and %hash gets a single key (that hash reference stringified) and a value of undef.

You wanted:

```
my %hash = ('inner1'=>{'foo'=>5},
            'inner2'=>{'bar'=>6});
```

As far as passing to subroutines goes, you can't pass hashes; code like you show flattens the hash into a list and then reassembles a hash from `@_`, but that will be a separate copy.  If you actually want the same hash, you must pass a hash reference instead.

Comment: +1 for `use warnings;` (and good answer, too). Also always `use strict;`.

Comment: I was using warnings, but I'm also using 5.012 which I think adds strict and warnings automatically.

Comment: @Eric Fossum: then you should have seen a 'Reference found where even-sized list expected' warning from your hash assignment

Comment: @ysth Does 'Reference found where even-sized list expected' mean it wasn't initialized?

Comment: No, it means you are assigning to a hash, which expects a list of alternating keys and values, but instead you are giving it a reference (in this case to a hash).  See http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Reference-found-where-even-sized-list-expected

Comment: and as a result, your hash becomes something useless like ('HASH(0x84f8818)' => undef)